# Google Maps API: Multiple GeoJson layers with MarkerClusterer + toggle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, toggle, geojson, markerclusterer

I have a problem with my GeoJson layers which I want to cluster (with MarkerClusterer) and then be able to show and hide them via checkboxes or similar. Therefore I tried something like the code below:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.515696, 13.392624),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var barLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    var cafeLayer = new google.maps.Data();

    barLayer.loadGeoJson('json/eat_drink/bar.geojson');
    cafeLayer.loadGeoJson('json/eat_drink/cafe.geojson');


    var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map); 
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
    markerClusterer.setMap(map);

    function displayMarkers(layer) { 
    var layer = layer;
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'addfeature', function (e) {
        if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.feature.getGeometry().get(),
                title: e.feature.getProperty('name'),
                map: map
            });
            // open the infoWindow when the marker is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker, e) {
                return function () {
                    var myHTML = e.feature.getProperty('name');
                    infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:150px; text-align: center;'>"+myHTML+"</div>");
                    infowindow.setPosition(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
                    infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)});
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            }(marker, e));
            markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
            bounds.extend(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
        }
    });
    layer.setMap(null);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

};

document.getElementById('bar').onclick = function(){            // enable and disable markers
        if(document.getElementById('bar').checked == true){
                displayMarkers(barLayer);
        }else{
            return null; 
        }
        };
}
```

Unfortunatley this doesn't work and I don't no exactly why. 
If I remove the displayMarkers() function around the code and replace "layer" with the desired GeoJson layer, e.g. "barLayer", it works just fine.
Since I will end up with tons of GeoJason layers I would prefer a "compact" solution like this insted of copying the code multiple times. Have you guys any ideas how to do that properly?

Comment: I don't see the definition of `displayMarkers()` anywhere in the code..

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: @enigma sorry my bad I copied the wrong piece of code. It's now corrected. That's also why the token was unexpected ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I haven't done much more than refactor your code. Could you give this a try, and if it doesn't work specify exactly what doesn't work?

```
function displayMarkers(layer, map, markerClusterer) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'addfeature', function(e) {
        if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.feature.getGeometry().get(),
                title: e.feature.getProperty('name'),
                map: map
            });
            // open the infoBox when the marker is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
                var myHTML = e.feature.getProperty('name');
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:150px; text-align: center;'>" + myHTML + "</div>");
                infowindow.setPosition(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
                infowindow.setOptions({
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
                    infowindow.close();
                });
            });
            markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().get());
        }
    });
    layer.setMap(null);
}

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.515696, 13.392624),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var barLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    var cafeLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    barLayer.loadGeoJson('json/eat_drink/bar.geojson');
    cafeLayer.loadGeoJson('json/eat_drink/cafe.geojson');
    var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map);
    markerClusterer.setMap(map);
    document.getElementById('bar').onclick = function() { // enable and disable streetViewControl
        if (document.getElementById('bar').checked == true) {
            displayMarkers(barlayer, map, markerClusterer);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. Unfortunately it still doesn't work, no markers will be displayed when checking the checkbox. The funny thing is that no error is thrown so i have really no idea why it doesn't work. The only thing i could think about ist the markerClusterer.setMap(map) function. Maybe it will not be updated when adding additional markers. If i console.log "markerClusterer" I can see that all markers are correctly added but are not set to map.

Comment: edit: I also tried to put the markerClusterer.setMap(map) in the .onclick function but then it throws an error (TypeError: this[Gb] is not a function)